# Faster way to concat dataframes with different columns vertically

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

I am trying to concat two huge dataframes (around 15GB) like the following:

a_df:

```
            A       B       C       D
2018-10-16  a16     b16     c16     d16
2018-10-17  a17     b17     c17     d17
2018-10-18  a18     b18     c18     d18
2018-10-19  a19     b19     c19     d19
2018-10-20  a20     b20     c20     d20
```

b_df:

```
            A       C       Y       Z       
2018-10-21  a21     c21     y21     z21     
2018-10-22  a22     c22     y22     z22
```

to get a final dataframe:

```
            A       B       C       D       Y       Z
2018-10-16  a16     b16     c16     d16
2018-10-17  a17     b17     c17     d17
2018-10-18  a18     b18     c18     d18
2018-10-19  a19     b19     c19     d19
2018-10-20  a20     b20     c20     d20
2018-10-21  a21             c21             y21     z21
2018-10-22  a22             c22             y22     z22
```

I am trying that code:

```
dfs = [a_df, b_df]

unique_columns = []
for df in dfs:
    for column in df.columns:
        unique_columns.append(column)
unique_columns = sorted(set(unique_columns))

same_columns_dfs = []
for df in dfs:
    empty_df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=df.index, columns=unique_columns)
    empty_df.loc[:, df.columns] = df.values
    same_columns_dfs.append(empty_df)

final_df = pd.concat(same_columns_dfs, axis=0, sort=True)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As your desired output, a straight `pd.concat` and `fillna` on the list of dfs will yield the output

```
dfs = [a_df, b_df]
df_out = pd.concat(dfs, sort=True).fillna('')

Out[176]:
              A    B    C    D    Y    Z
2018-10-16  a16  b16  c16  d16
2018-10-17  a17  b17  c17  d17
2018-10-18  a18  b18  c18  d18
2018-10-19  a19  b19  c19  d19
2018-10-20  a20  b20  c20  d20
2018-10-21  a21       c21       y21  z21
2018-10-22  a22       c22       y22  z22
```